# Let a connection to server be open all the time

Tags: java, memory-leaks, sms, smtp, jsmpp

I am working on SMS application for a company, that sends SMS messages (SUBMIT_SM command) and receives the response from the SMSC (SUBMIT_SM_RESP command) to indicates if it is delivered to the customer. I am using [JSMPP API](http://code.google.com/p/jsmpp/wiki/GettingStarted).

What is the best practice to connect to the SMSC server? Should I open one connection (one session) and use it through the whole application to send SMS messages (any memory leakage here)? Or should I connect/disconnect to/from the SMSC server every time I send SMS message (any delays here)?

Note that, we are sending about 1000-2000 SMS messages per hour. Also I noticed that JSMPP API receives the response message (SUBMIT_SM_RESP) only when the connection is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the connection implementation. If your connection won't "die" during a long break than use one connection as it will save you time openeing/closing per request.

If your application is multi-threaded (where more than one thread can send a message) I advice you to implement a connection pool mechanism (or use an available one which supports SMSC sessions).

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer! And indeed, my application is multi-threaded. Does it make any difference to use multiple sessions rather than using a single session across all the threads? Also, are there any memory leakage issues regarding the always-open connection?

Comment: There is no leakage problem in opening one session (as long as you close it at the end of course). Its actually preferred and the most easiest way to do it. But since more than one thread is going to use the session you need to verify that this session is synchronized (check vendor docs for this as I cannot guarantee this synchronization)